JSdoc vscode intellisense on monkey patched / added function?
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.
Just wondering if there's any way to accomplish having the moo method referenced in other places on VS code populate intellisense using jsdoc. Right now it just shows any.
lib/newmoment.js
/**
 * @module lib/newmoment
 */
const moment = require('moment');

/**
 * do the moo
 * @returns {String} moo
 */
moment.moo = function(){
  return 'moo'
}

module.exports = moment;

test.js which uses lib/newmoment.js
const moment_modified = require('./lib/newmoment')

console.log(moment_modified.moo());

Screenshots showing any, however I'm trying to get the intellisense to show do the moo:
referenced function
original function

Update...
I found a way to sort of hack in what I was looking for without an intersection type using JSdoc (your mileage may vary). Screenshots with results below. It is not the cleanest for sure, but may at least get you by until you have the chance to refactor code (see @adsy suggestions)
updated lib/newmoment.js
/**
 * @namespace NewMoment
 */
const NewMoment = {
  /**
    * do the moo
    * @returns {String} moo
  */
  moo(){}
}

/**
 * @type {NewMoment}
 */
const moment = require('moment');

moment.moo = function(){
  return 'moo'
}

module.exports = moment;

test.js remains the same as before
in test.js, shows jsdoc
in lib/newmoment.js, shows jsdoc

The easiest way would be to use an intersection type (&) between the original type and the new type. Object.assign already implies this, and also requires an object literal to be passed for that "new type".
In turn, object literals are easy to markup with further JSDoc.
/**
 * @module lib/newmoment
 */

const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = Object.assign(moment, {
    /**
     * do the moo
     * @returns {String} moo
     */
    moo() {
        return 'moo';
    }
});

Note both this and your original example actually mutate the original module, which is not great practice. You may wish to use Object.assign({}, moment, { // ...etc.

understood - I would like to refactor the actual code to not mutate the original module to do something like a proxy or just a separate module entirely. But that requires other dependency refactor first

Yeh. If you moved to ESM module you couldn't actually do what this code does anyway since they are immutable. Its only working currently because its using old commonjs module syntax.

Yeah, the joys of large aged projects. I'd also like to move to ESM someday as well, but it's not feasible today with the current dependencies of the project and extensive codebase refactoring required.
thanks for the tips though - I'll try to see if I can get an intersection type to play nice with JSdoc and original module functionality. It would be great to have the intellisense on some functions so I don't have to keep manually looking up the function params.
